# Having some problems with a simple IPv6 TCP client

Tags: c, tcp, ipv6

For some reason this keeps on throwing an error when it tries to connect to the server. The server in this case was written by the professor so I am sure that it works but I cannot seem to get this to work for me despite checking it multiple times and running all sorts of test. I will say that htons takes port 5000 and changes it which I believe it is supposed to and for some reason "::1" is also transformed to {0,0,0,0,0,0,256} in serverInfo.sin6_addr after going through inet_pton(). I believe that one of these could be the issue but it doesn't seem to matter if I hard code it in.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>

#define RCVBUFSIZ 50

void DisplayFatalErr(char *errMsg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct sockaddr_in6 serverInfo;

    //verify the args
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough entries. Please try again.");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        char* serverIPaddr = argv[1];
        int serverport = atoi(argv[2]);
        char* msg = argv[3];
        size_t msgLen = sizeof(msg);
        //make word for the sending of the message.
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("Winsock did not start properly");
            exit(1);
        }
        //create the socket
        int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            DisplayFatalErr("socket() function failed.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Socket connection was successful");
            //getchar();
        }
        serverInfo.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        serverInfo.sin6_port = htons(serverport);
        inet_pton(AF_INET6, serverIPaddr, &serverInfo.sin6_addr);
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serverInfo, sizeof(serverInfo)) < 0)
        {
            DisplayFatalErr("connect() function failed.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Connection acheived.");
        }
        //send the message
        if (send(sock, msg, msgLen, 0) != msgLen)
        {
            DisplayFatalErr("Send error.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Messenge sent.");
        }
        //recieve the message
        int n = 0;
        int len = 0;
        char rcvBuffer[BUFSIZ];
        char* mrcvBuffer = rcvBuffer;
        while ((n = recv(sock, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)
        {
            mrcvBuffer += n;
            len += n;

            rcvBuffer[len] = '\0';
            printf("Got a message: '%s'\n", rcvBuffer);
        }
        printf("You reached the end \n");
        close(sock);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `size_t msgLen = sizeof(msg);` --> `size_t msgLen = strlen(msg);`, otherwise you get the size of a pointer

Comment: Thank you! That said even with that edit I still get error 10049 from the connect function. I have looked into my settings and IPv6 is enabled and I have turned off my firewall.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that you forget to set/fill the `serverInfo.sin6_addr.s6_addr` member

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to zero out serverInfo before setting it.

Comment: Good to know ;)